# Web User Control Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, webusercontrol

I know this is somewhat of a beginner question but I can't remember how to do this.

I have a web user control and it inherits from an interface with a single property.

So the user control looks like this in my aspx page;

```
<uc1:PublishPricingCalculator ID="PublishPricingCalculator" runat="server" bookId='<%=book.BookId %>' />
```

In my code behind I have this;

```
    [BrowsableAttribute(true)]
    public string bookId { get; set; }
```

However, when I inspect the value being passed from the UI i see `'<%=book.BookId %>'` instead of my GUID.

I know I can use LoadControl but is there a way I can pass a C# variable to my user control?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to use a different syntax:

```
bookId=<%# book.BookId %>
```

Comment: I get this exception "The name 'book' does not exist in the current context".  Am I missing something?

Comment: what is book? is it a variable defined in the code behind? If so is it public or at least protected?

Comment: it's a variable defined in the code behind as a public property.  it's an object and one of its properties is bookid

Comment: book is an object of the aspx page not the ascx btw

Comment: my thoughts exactly.  might just mean i need to LoadControl which would be a huge pain as this is a legacy system and i'd need to recode quite a bit.

Comment: can you access book outside of the control declaration on the code in front of the aspx page?

Comment: oh yeah, no problem there at all.

Comment: and you are using `<%#` instead of `<%=` ?